# How to implement a javascripts callback to change a Bokeh graph title

Tags: javascript, bokeh

I simply want to allow the user to be able to change the title of a Bokeh graph. Here's a minimal example of the code I have tried. The problem is how the callback is made.

```
from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, Button

fig = figure(title='title')
fig.line(x=[1,2,3], y=[1,2,3])


callback = CustomJS(args={'title':fig.title}, code="""title.text = text_input.get('value');
""")

text_input = TextInput(title="Add graph title", value='', callback=callback)


widgets_layout = column(text_input)


figures_layout = row(fig)


page_layout = row(widgets_layout, fig)


script, div = components(page_layout)
return render_to_response('fig.html', {'script': script, 'div': div})
```

I am not getting any errors but nothing happens when I enter a new title in the TextInput field.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `.get(...)` syntax was removed a long time ago. In any fairly recent version of Bokeh, just access e.g. `.value` directly. Also, for the `text_input` to be defined inside the callback, you need to pass it in `args`. Here is a updated version of your code:

```
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.layouts import column, row
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, TextInput
from bokeh.plotting import figure


fig = figure(title='title')
fig.line(x=[1,2,3], y=[1,2,3])

text_input = TextInput(title="Add graph title", value='')
text_input.js_on_change('value', CustomJS(
    args={'title': fig.title, 'text_input': text_input},
    code="title.text = text_input.value"
))

widgets_layout = column(text_input)

figures_layout = row(fig)

show(row(widgets_layout, fig))
```

HOWEVER, with Bokeh >= 1.1, you can just use `js_link` and avoid having to create a `CustomJS` altogether:

```
text_input = TextInput(title="Add graph title", value='')
text_input.js_link('value', fig.title, 'text')
```

Comment: if you have a problem with title issue with above code, dont forget specify title in fig. I mean dont leave figure without title. I did before and made some errors :)

Comment: Yes, passing a `title` string to `figure` is actually a shortcut for adding a `TItle` annotation to the plot, and that is what must actually be linked.